# Mediawiki Templates

Tags: php, wikimedia, wikimedia-commons

I'm new to `mediawiki` and I am having troubles on the templates. I have installed all of [Liquipedia](https://github.com/Liquipedia)'s extensions.
On liquipedia's [Tab:Static](https://liquipedia.net/commons/Template:Tabs_static), everything works fine. But on my part, while I'm testing it out on my local. It doesn't have the exact output that I'm expecting.

Here is the picture of the output to point it out:

[image]

And this is the output that I want.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, you have a template loop. Liquipedia uses the documentation template to display this documentation from a subpage with  tags to avoid this.